# Why are global and static objects stored in the section of bss

Tags: c++, binary, objdump

I'm studying the sections of a binary file. I used the c++ code below:

```
// test.cpp
struct Test {
    int i;
    Test(int ii) : i(ii) {}
    Test() {}
};

Test t0{5};
Test t1 = Test(5);
Test t2;
static Test t3;
static Test t4{5};

int i = 1;
int j;
static int k;
static int l = 1;


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code with the command `g++ test.cpp` and get a binary file named `a.out`.

Then, I used the command `objdump` to extract the sections of `bss` and `data`.

The output of `objdump -dj .data a.out`:

```
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000201000 <__data_start>:
        ...

0000000000201008 <__dso_handle>:
  201008:       08 10 20 00 00 00 00 00                             .. .....

0000000000201010 <i>:
  201010:       01 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201014 <_ZL1l>:
  201014:       01 00 00 00                                         ....
```

The output of `objdump -dj .bss a.out`:

```
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .bss:

0000000000201018 <__bss_start>:
  201018:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
        ...

000000000020101c <t0>:
  20101c:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201020 <t1>:
  201020:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201024 <t2>:
  201024:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201028 <j>:
  201028:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

000000000020102c <_ZStL8__ioinit>:
  20102c:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201030 <_ZL2t3>:
  201030:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201034 <_ZL2t4>:
  201034:       00 00 00 00                                         ....

0000000000201038 <_ZL1k>:
        ...
```

So, the variables `i` and `l` are stored in the section `.data` because they were initialized. The variables `j` and `k` are in the section `.bss` because they were not initialized. I can understand that.

But why are all of the objects of `Test` are in the section `.bss` even if those initialized objects? I thought `t0`, `t1` and `t4` should be stored in the section `.data` but obviously I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.data` is only used for variables that are initialized with literal data.

The `Test` objects are initialized using the constructor method. So the memory is allocated in `bss`, then during startup the constructor is called to fill in the contents.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the accepted answer: there are ways to alter this behavior. It was already discussed in many places, for example:
[Guaranteeing static (constant) initialization of static objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175697/guaranteeing-static-constant-initialization-of-static-objects)

Here are my tests:

```
struct Test1 {
    int a;
};
struct Test2 {
    Test2(const int pa) : a(pa) {}
    int a;
};
struct Test3 {
    constexpr Test3(const int pa) : a(pa) {}
    Test3(double d) : a((int)d) {}
    int a;
};
struct Test4 {
    int a {0x12345604};
};
Test1 s_test1 { 0x12345601 };//Object is placed directly in .data. No constructor executed.
Test2 s_test2 { 0x12345602 };//Object is placed .bss, initialization value is in .rodata and constructor is executed during initialization
Test3 s_test3_1 { 0x12345603 };//Object is placed directly in .data. No constructor executed.
Test3 s_test3_2 { 0.0 };//Object is placed .bss, init data is in .rodata and constructor is executed during initialization
Test4 s_test4;//Object is placed directly in .data. No constructor executed.
```

(I verified with g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 and arm-none-eabi-g++ (15:6.3.1+svn253039-1build1) 6.3.1 20170620)

So, if you have a very large static object, make sure you initialize it via constexpr constructor to avoid doubling memory consumption and slow constructor invokation.